# Return multiple arrays from method

Tags: c#

I want to return multiple arrays from a method, which uses a few if statements. I've tested the body of the code, and it works for itself. Now I want to recreate it into a method I can call, but I get some errors (not all code path return a value). 
I know that the error lies in that one if statement doesn't send anything return, but I'm not sure how I can fix the error and still obtain the functionality I want.

Here's the code of the method:

```
private byte[] GetParameterBuff(string[] statement, ref byte[] tdi, ref byte[] tdo, ref byte[] mask, ref byte[] smask)
{
    string[] parameters;
    char[] delimiter = new char[] { '(', ')' };
    int numBits = Convert.ToInt32(statement[1]);

    if (numBits > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The amount of bits sent in the message is: " + numBits);
        for (int p = 2; p < statement.Length; p++)
        {
            parameters = statement[p].Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if (parameters[0] == "TDI")
            {
                tdi = ConvertHexStringToByteArray(parameters[1]);
                foreach (byte b in tdi)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The tdi array is: " + b);
                }
                return tdi;

            }

            else if (parameters[0] == "TDO")
            {
                tdo = ConvertHexStringToByteArray(parameters[1]);
                foreach (byte b in tdo)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The tdo array is: " + b);
                }
                return tdo;
            }

            else if (parameters[0] == "MASK")
            {
                mask = ConvertHexStringToByteArray(parameters[1]);
                foreach (byte b in mask)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The mask array is: " + b);
                }
                return mask;
            }

            else if (parameters[0] == "SMASK")
            {
                smask = ConvertHexStringToByteArray(parameters[1]);
                foreach (byte b in smask)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The smask array is: " + b);
                }
                return smask;
            }

            else
            {
                return null;
            }


        }

        return ??;

    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The amount of bits sent in the message is: " + numBits);
        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: Create a class that encapsulates the arrays. Return a reference to an object instantiated from that class.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you elaborate or send links to sites that can?

Comment: Why do you use a loop if you return from it immediately? It is not very clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I edited your code a bit for brevity, functionality should be the same.

Comment: I would break this method down even further. It's still a lot of code for one method. Maybe create a sub method for each check/if statement. That will make it a lot easier to see where your code is returning and where you need to return a `null` or throw an `Exception` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use "out" syntax for multiple return values you should use `out byte[] tdi` rather than `ref byte[] tdi`. This communicates that the caller does not have to supply a existing value. It does however mean that you need to assign each out parameter before returning from the method.

To return multiple values you could use ValueTuple syntax, i.e.

```
public (byte[] tdi, byte[] tdo, byte[] mask) GetParameterBuff(string[] statement)
```

This start to  become unreadable when you need to return many parameters. In that case it might be a good idea to introduce a small class, i.e.

```
public class MyArrays
{
    public byte[] Tdi { get; }
    public byte[] Tdo { get; }
    public byte[] Mask { get; }

    public MyArrays(byte[] tdi, byte[] tdo, byte[] mask)
    {
        Tdi = tdi;
        Tdo = tdo;
        Mask = mask;
    }
}
```

Regardless of what method you use you will need to decide what to return if some conditions are not satisfied.

- Exception
- Null
- A Maybe/Option
- bool returning success/fail, and out parameter(s) for values